# How to bypass "refreshLayout.html" restriction for page

Tags: apostrophe-cms

In this [line](https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe/blob/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/index.js#L548) of the apostrophe-templates module it states that a jquery get call will set the `req.xhr` and as a result the `refreshLayout.html` template will be used, which means you don't get the entire page.

However this seems restrictive and we need a way to override it, because what if I actually just wanted the entire page for say animation purposes, or crawling purposes using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

As you know I am the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

It's easy to change the AJAX behavior. Just use a `pageBeforeSend` handler in any module to set a property in `req.data` and, in your `refreshLayout.html`, use that as the argument to `extend`.

```
// in any module
self.pageBeforeSend = function(req) {
  req.data.ajaxLayout = 'modulename:layoutname.html';
};

// in your refreshLayout.html
{% extend data.ajaxLayout %}
```

This is the same technique that allows your page templates or inner layout to extend either the outer layout or the ajax layout.